# How to copy just timestamps, or "I should have used cp -p"

Tags: rsync, cp

I foolishly copied a very large amount of data using `cp -r`.

Looking at it now, I've realized that this means I lost my file modification times. I *should* have used `cp -rp`.

My directory structure and files haven't changed: is there any way to copy over just the attributes/timestamps now? I'm thinking `rsync` might be useful.

Comment: Yes, `rsync` would be useful.  In general, you only have to run `rsync` with the same source and dest as the original `cp -r`.  but test it with `rsync --dry-run` first.

Answer (score 4):

This worked well for me:

```
rsync -vrt --size-only /src /dest
```

`/src` being folder which timestamps are correct and wanted. `/dest` folder files will acquire modification times of the /src folder files. Create times remained unchanged.

The `--size-only` command compares files only based on size, which was largely unchanged for me. The `-t` copies over the timestamps.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `find` and `touch`.

```
cd destination
find -depth -exec touch -r /path/to/source/{} {} \;
```

The `-depth` option arranges for directories' times to be set after their contents have been set. This assumes that your `find` interpolates `{}` when it's a substring of an argument. If it doesn't, invoke a shell:

```
find -depth -exec sh -c 'for x; do touch -r "$0/$x" "$x"' /path/to/source {} +
```

To copy the access times as well, run `touch -a …` as well.

```
find -depth -exec touch -a -r /path/to/source/{} {} \; -exec touch -r /path/to/source/{} {} \;
```